# Vector over field GF(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V = \{i ∈ \Bbb Z \mid  0 ≤ i < 2^n\}$ for some given positive integer n. Define operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication on V in such a way as to turn it into a vector space over the field GF(2).

I know that GF(2) = {0,1} and
+: 0 + 0 = 0, 0 + 1 = 1, and 1 + 1 = 0.
*: 0 * 0 = 0, 0 * 1 = 0, and  1 * 1 = 1.
and GF(2^n) = {0,1,a, a^2,...,a^n-2}
but i'm not sure how to start this problem

Answer (score 1):

Do you know a binary operation named $\texttt{xor}$, which is fast to compute by computer, so computer scientists uses it frequently? That's the vector addition you need. consider $n = 4,$ and we want to compute addition $10 \oplus 2$. First, write them in binary.
$$
\begin{array}{llllllllll}
10&=&1&0&1&0\\
2&=&0&0&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
then, do addition on $\mathbb F_2$ for each place, that is:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
1 \oplus 0=1 \\
0 \oplus 0=0 \\
1 \oplus 1 = 0 \\
0 \oplus 0 = 0.
\end{array}
$$
so $10 \oplus 2 = 8$, because $8 = (1000)_2$.

vector-number multiplaction: you can get it even by the definition of vector space - because there's only 2 elements in $\mathbb F_2$ - which is the identity of addition, and identity of multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here (to what I suspect is the intended approach) is to find a way to think of an element of $V$ as a vector in $[GF(2)]^n$. Once you do that, the corresponding definition of addition and scalar multiplication is natural.

One simple way to identify an element of $V$ with a vector of $GF(2)$ elements is to look at each numbers binary representation. For example, with $n = 8$, the identification might look like this:
$$
99 = 01100011_2 \longleftrightarrow [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1].
$$
One valid ways of "adding" two numbers in $V$ is as follows: add the corresponding vectors over $[GF(2)]^n$ and yield the number whose digits in binary are the entries of the sum. The definition of multiplication by the elements $0,1$ is exactly the "common sense" definition.